# Python, finding circles in image

Tags: python, detection, hough-transform

I'm using the cv2.HoughCircles in Python trying to detect circles in the following image.[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFmZ1.png)

here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image.png")
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 10, param1=20, param2=60, minRadius=0, maxRadius=40)
print(circles)
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 3, y - 3), (x + 3, y + 3), (0, 128, 255), -1)
    plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray"), plt.title("corners")
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(output, cmap="gray"), plt.title("corners")
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
```

[the detected circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBTtA.png)

any insight on why it isn't detecting the circles?

attaching an image of the circles i would like to detect. i would like to detect as many circles like the ones in red in the following image.[example of circles i would like to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2KTG.jpg)

Comment: It would help if you could point out what circles you would like to detect in your image.

Comment: thanks for your input. I attached an image with examples of the circles i would like to detect.